# Does the azimuth angle matter for determining the electron density for atomic orbitals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, electrons, orbitals

The only place in the expression for the wavefunction where the azimuth angle $\phi$ is used is in the equation for the spherical harmonics, and in the spherical harmonics there is only a single complex exponential term which makes use of the azimuth angle.

$$e^{\mathrm{i}m_l\phi}$$

If I am correct in saying that the only place the asimuth angle is used in the expression of the wavefunction is a multiplication by that complex exponential, then as $|e^{\mathrm{i}x}| = 1 \ \forall\ x \in \mathbb{R}$ and the electron density is given by$|\Psi|^2$ it stands to reason that the probability of finding an electron should not depend on the azimuth angle $\phi$. However, I commonly see diagrams depicting both the elevation $\theta$ and azimuth $\phi$ affecting the orbitals, as shown below. What is going on here?

[image]

Comment: They are plotting something different ;-). Specifically, the sine and the cosine that took can form as linear superpositions of the two signs of the magnetic quantum number.

Comment: Experimentally, we have voluminous, strong evidence that molecular bonding is directional. We cannot understand chemistry without this. So, what do you conclude from this fact?

Comment: @JohnDoty what I would conclude from that is that the bonding doesnt only depend on the magnitude if the wavefunction, it also depends on the phase. I am not sure if this is correct though. With that being said, would I be correct in saying that the electron density doesn't depend on the azimuth angle?

Comment: Phase relative to what reference?

Comment: I guess the phase difference between the two orbitals for bonding? I really am not well studied in this area though so these are just guesses.